# An app that allows to listen to music across mobiles instead of sharing same earphones

Tags: android, iphone-app

I want to listen to a song playing on my mobile along with my friend. We generally share earphones.

I need an app that allows him to listen to the same song that is playing on my mobile through his mobile so that instead of sharing earphones from my mobile, he can use his own mobile to listen to the song playing in my mobile. I am using android mobile and she is using iPhone app.